# need help in unix for iterating a for loop

Tags: unix, for-loop

The bellow line code is not working.it is not iterating  through the directory.

```
input={20132802,20132802}
for i in $(ls -1 /home/$input/*s.log)
do
...
done
```

but when providing the input in the loop working fine.

```
for i in $(ls -1 /home/{20132802,20132802}/*s.log)
do
...
done
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansion cannot be used in variables because it is performed before any other expansions.
From `man bash`:

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To
>   avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion.

However, you can use `eval` to overcome this limitation:

```
input={20132802,20132802}
for i in $(eval ls -1 /home/$input/*s.log)
do
...
done
```

Obligatory reading: [`eval` is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Answer (score -1):

Try writing ${input} instead of $input since i is the index of the for loop and I guess $i is used when you write $input ('$i'nput).

Comment: Its not working.the ls command is not iterating through the directories.